# cannot add/push google-services.json in android studio to github

Tags: git, github

I downloaded `google-services.json` file and put it in my local machine. I committed and pushed it to my github repository. When I tried to pull from the github repository on my other PC, I could not see the `google-services.json` file.

How can I push `google-services.json` file to github? Or is it not possible at all because it contains confidential information?

But I saw some people could add the file on their github repository.

Comment: Solutions should be posted as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git add` + `git commit` + `git push` should do the job? Are you sure you added the file and committed it? Was it shown in the commit? If you work with GitHub was it shown online?

> How can I push google-services.json file to github? Or is it not possible at all because it contains confidential information?

No, Git/GitHub doesn't check whether information is confidential or not.

**Edit:** The file was mentioned in the `gitignore` file. That was the reason why the problem occurred.

Comment: I tried `git add` + `git commit` + `git push`. `git add` is not adding the file to the stage. I can `add` and `push` everything else, and they work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to exclude "google-services.json" from `gitignore`. it is working now

Answer (score 2):

The reason is "google-services.json" is added to .gitignore. At big projects it may be bot an easy task to find an ".gitignore" that contains such exclusion. 
You may force-add your file, that will add it to git:

```
git add someProject/src/someFlavor/google-services.json -f
```